# WordPress settings page upload logo

Tags: php, wordpress, api, upload, settings

i have been struggling with this for the last few good hours..
I'm trying to create my own theme settings page and i got to the logo upload field
and now i'm stuck.. I looked through posts here and on Google but i'm still missing something and can't get it done..

I added to my theme functions.php-

```
    register_setting( 'empathy-settings', 'empathy-setting-logo' );
add_settings_section( 'section-three', '', 'section_three_callback', 'empathy-design' );
add_settings_field( 'logo-image', 'Website Logo', 'field_logo_callback', 'empathy-design', 'section-three' );

function admin_scripts_upload() {
   wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
   wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
   wp_register_script('empathy-logo-upload', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/uploader.js', 
   array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
   wp_enqueue_script('empathy-logo-upload');
}
function admin_styles_upload() {
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

function section_three_callback() { }

function field_logo_callback() {
    $setting = esc_attr( get_option( 'empathy-setting-logo' ) );

    echo '<img src="" id="thenewlogo" />';
    echo '<div style="width:100%; float:left;">';

        echo '<input type="text" name="empathy-setting-logo" id="empathy-setting-logo" style="width:200px;" />';
        echo '<br /><a id="empathy-setting-logo-button">Upload</a>';

    echo '</div>';
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'admin_scripts_upload');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_styles_upload');
```

I created uploader.js with the code-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#empathy-setting-logo-button').click(function() {
     targetfield = jQuery('#empathy-setting-logo');
     tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
     return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
     imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
     jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
     tb_remove();
}
```

});

The media library shows and the files are being uploaded but i can't "Insert to post"
so i can't save the image URL.

How can i get it done please?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
<input type="text" name="new_img" id="new_img" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'empathy-setting-logo' ) ); ?>">
<a class="button" onclick="upload_image('new_img');">Upload Favicon</a>
```

And here the JS-Function:

```
var uploader;
function upload_image(id) {

  //Extend the wp.media object
  uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Choose Image',
    button: {
      text: 'Choose Image'
    },
    multiple: false
  });

  //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
  uploader.on('select', function() {
    attachment = uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    var url = attachment['url'];
    jQuery('#'+id).val(url);
  });

  //Open the uploader dialog
  uploader.open();
}
</script>
```

Make sure you added the following to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_media' );
```